# How to Stick any news post in home page in a website built in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, widget, content-management-system

Hello I am very new to CMS (Wordpress).I have a news post website built in wordpress.I want to stick any post to the homepage which seems to me popular and after a sertain amount of time i will unstick it.I tried some plugins such as SM Sticky Clicky Star,Ultimate Post Slider Widget etc but they did not work.Can anyone please suggested me some plugins or widgets to solve this problem.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an very easy and step by step solution of how to display the Staick posts in the WordPress Website. If you follow this documentation it will be very easy and mindblowing to create so that you can rock on wiht the code.

How to Display the Latest Sticky Posts in WordPress

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-display-the-latest-sticky-posts-in-wordpress/

Hope so this Tutorial help you for creating stick posts to appear on WordPress Site.

Thanks :)